# Get Windows Username in ASP.NET without System.Web

Tags: asp.net, authentication, system.web

I have a reporting dll that is used in ASP.NET (Windows Authentication) and winforms projects. Sometimes it needs the username so if it was running in ASP.NET it would use:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

and in windows

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Now I am trying to move to .NET 4 Client Profile so I need to avoid the System.Web reference in the reporting dll. Is there an alternative way to get the Windows Username for when the dll is running in ASP.NET which won't use System.Web. The only way I can currently see to avoid System.Web is to pass the Username as a parameter which will be a pain to adjust for in every report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) property of the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class:

```
using System.Threading;

string userName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Won't this bring up the user under which the site is running on the web server? Where as I need the authenticated end user.

Comment: @Pete, since you're using Windows authentication, the thread should be impersonating the authenticated user, so `CurrentPrincipal` should behave as you expect. I did not test it, though (no web server handy right now).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Environment.UserName which lives in System.

Comment: If you're using an AD account to run your IIS site, this will pick up the account running the site, not the user that is visiting the site. Just FYI to others using this

Answer (score 0):

System.Web namespace is definitely available in an ASP.Net application. You can definitely make use of it. Apart from that, you will also have the Membership providers that you can use to validate or tell the current user name.

Comment: But you can't add the System.Web reference to an underlying dll you intend to be on the client profile for when in use by WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Using System.net -- NetworkCredential.Username?

Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.username.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If Windows authentication is on this might work: **Page.User.Identity.Name**
In my case, it does.