# SSO in ASP VB.NET Application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, single-sign-on

I am wanting my Vb.net application to "know who is logged on" similar to the way SharePoint does.  When I start SharePoint 2013, I'm not asked for a username or password, it just "knows" who I am because I've already authenticated through Windows.

Is there a tutorial somewhere that can demonstrate how this is done?  All of the users of this application are inside the same Active Directory on a corporate network.

Comment: Hello Scott, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately your question is a bit too broad to be useful in this format, but you can try looking at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323176 for information on implenting Windows Authentication in your ASP.NET application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Windows Username in ASP.NET without System.Web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748976/get-windows-username-in-asp-net-without-system-web)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx, a "How to" implement Forms Authentication with Membership and Active Directory.

This technology is a bit old, but still usable.

A better approach would be to use the new [OWIN Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) if you have Azure Active Directory

Comment: Also, you can use [this tutorial](http://example.com) for On-Premise Authentication